# How can we create and returns a 404 page, if someone access pages via url without login

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Where do we add a `404` page if some one try to access Home or any other page via `url` for eg: `http://localhost:3000/home` without login. The Home, Profile, Aboutus pages are accessible only after successful login.

`App.js`

```
const App = () => {                     
  return (
   <UserProfileContext.Provider value={{ data, setData }}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <>
     <Navigation />
      <Switch>
          <ProtectedRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/aboutus" component={Aboutus} />
          <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </>
   </BrowserRouter>
  </UserProfileContext.Provider>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(App, null),
  document.getElementById("root")
);

export default App;
```

`Navigation.js`

```
const Navigation = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const { data } = useContext(UserProfileContext); // added 16 jun based on stack

    const divStyle = {
        float:'left',
        color: '#64cad8', 
        padding: '0px 0px 0px 10px',
        font:'Lucida, sans-serif'
      };

    function logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem('loginEmail')
        localStorage.removeItem('Privilege')
        history.push('/login')
        window.location.reload(true);
      }

    return localStorage.getItem('loginEmail') &&
        <div className="App">
            <div className="wrapper">
                <nav className="siteNavigation_nav_links">
                <div className="clubLogo landing"style={divStyle}><b>Southside Soccer</b></div>
                    <NavLink className="mobile_register_link" to="/">Home</NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="mobile_register_link" to="/profile">Profile</NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="mobile_login_link" to="/login" onClick={logout}>Logout</NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="mobile_login_link" to='/aboutus'>About us</NavLink>
                <div className="profileImage nav menu">
                <span>{data.name}</span>|<img src={data.photo}></img>
                </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
}

export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for 404 page or error page do this:

`<Route path="*" component={ErrorPage} />`

remember to use `exact` on the routes you want views to be accessible at

your protected route should redirect to your login page if not successfully authenticated

Comment: Thanks, created and that is working fine. Accepted and upvoted

Answer (score 2):

A 404 error is when a page is not found - I think what you are looking for is a 401 error (which is an unauthorised access error). Firstly I'll answer your question; to handle a 401 error in react-router you typically you use default routes:

In earlier react-router:

```
<Route path='*' component={NotFoundComponent} />
```

In newer react router (version 4 and 5) just place the route last:

```
<Route path="/404" component={GenericNotFound} />
<Redirect to="/404" />
```

However, this will not solve your issue. What you want do do is show an error page if the user is not logged in. NOT whenever a user accesses an url that doesn't exist.

**So there's two ways to do what you want.** The first way is with a server (this is how it's usually done in the industry). You have three pages (login-page.js, 401-error.js, main-app.js). First the server sends the login-page.js. Then when a user logs in, you send the main-app.js page. If a user is not logged in but tries to access an url on the main-app.js then you send the 401-error.js page.

**I understand that this carries a lot of overhead though so instead you can do it a slightly easier but less secure way through a single page application - which is probably what you intend to do anyway.**

First you need to maintain some state about whether or not the user is logged in globally throughout your app (probably with redux). **Then in each of your components (Home, Profile etc.) you have to check if a user is logged in, if not then redirect to the 404 page.**

You can use `history` to redirect to a page programatically: [Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

```js
 
 class Foo extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      if (reduxStore.userIsLoggedIn === false) {
          this.props.history.push('/401')
      }
    }
    /** -- snip -- **/
 }
 
 /** -- snip -- **/
 <Route render={({ history }) => 
     <Foo history={history}/>
 }/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In start of each page, you mush check login (variables) status of every user! If he/she has not login, redirect him/her to appropriate page! For example a page which show a message that "you need to login first".